# How to build Strace on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, strace

I have Ubuntu v.14.04 installed on my laptop. I downloaded strace-4.15 from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/). I successfully configure the package through `.\configure` command but when i apply `make` command it gives following error in the `pathtrace.c`. error is shown in the image below.
[image]

Kindly help me to remove this error.
Thankyou.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to compile it yourself? Is it not available in the repositories?

Comment: I am using it first time and simply following the directions given in the INSTALL file of strace folder. Can i trace the system calls without compiling the strace??

Comment: Just install it from the repositories: `sudo apt install strace`

Comment: I have tried this command `sudo apt install strace`. The output is "strace is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded". tell me how would i come to know that strace is installed on the machine?

Comment: OK...? So strace is already installed. What's the problem?

Comment: why it shows such error in pathtrace.c when i apply `make` command?

Comment: Why even try to build it if it's already installed? If you're not able to solve compilation issues then don't compile it yourself and just use the one from the repositories.

Comment: It means i do not have to bother about the error. This tool is new for me. Thank you so much for guidance.

Comment: If i want to trace the system calls of Android applications on the android device, is it necessary to install the ubuntu on the machine?? or it can be done on windows?

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.